# How to make a modulus series in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, modulus

For my problem I need to figure out how to make the remainder of a modulus division problem continue into another calculation in visual basic. It is really difficult to word, so I will try to use an example:

The user enters 4500.
 4500 mod 1000 = 4 times with a remainder of 500.

Now I need the 500 to continue into the next calculation.

500 mod 100 = 5

Then the output may read: Boxes of 1000: 4
                          Boxes of 100: 5

Can anyone explain how I would code a problem similar to this in Visual Basic?

Comment: Mod returns the remainder... `500 mod 100` is zero.

Comment: What you want to do is use integers (which will truncate any fractional remainder) with division. `4500 / 1000` will be `4`, so long as your variable is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dividend As Integer = 4500/1000         ' results to 4
Dim remainder As Integer = 4500 Mod 1000    ' results to 500
Dim subdividend As Integer = remainder/100  ' results to 5
```